# Weblogic or JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, weblogic

I am a long time Java developer on JBoss(and Tomcat). In the last year I had to develop over WebLogic and I have to say - I really miss JBoss.

Since my experience with WebLogic is pretty shallow, I am asking the more experienced guys out there: 
Is there a reason for spending money on WebLogic? 
Isn't JBoss giving you all that you need?

Comment: Why waste money on WebLogic when any other application server package can easily be substituted - aka JBoss, Tomcat, Glassfish plus extras etc.

Comment: if i want to deploy simple app on weblogic server then i to pay for licence right.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I suspect the reason Weblogic gets chosen is a pleasant sales person comes to visit a manager with money to spend, gives him the sales pitch and hey-presto, the company is using Weblogic.  I don't know if the JBoss support contract comes with a sales force, but would be surprised if it did and that the playing field has leveled in that respect.

In my experience, other than the pretty console you get with Weblogic (which isn't worth forking out the license fees for) there's not much between the 2.  I suspect these days JBoss has market share (just guessing that), which in my book that translates into more help available online, etc when you're stuck on something.

It's also worth considering that the Weblogic licenses (last time I saw them) where the usual server-side terms - per-processor, per-box, etc.  This will limit you in scalability terms because with JBoss you can keep adding hardware without occurring extra cost, while with Weblogic your licenses will need upgrading too.

Whichever you choose you're going to be able to build your system on top of them without too much trouble, but my preference would be JBoss.

Answer (score 27):

I *really* like WebLogic.  I'll suspend the licensing cost for the moment and just say that in their heyday they were the best Java EE app server on the market, hands down.  BEA had a lot of extremely talented people developing their code, and it showed.  If money was not part of the equation, and I had an employer that insisted on spending money that wasn't mine, I'd still choose WebLogic over WebSphere or JBOSS or Glassfish or anything else on the market.

I'm saddened by Oracle's purchase.  I think that the talent has leaked away, and Oracle has no clear idea of what they want to do with WebLogic.  They've been stuck on version 10.1 for a few years now.

```
    <prejudice-ahead>
Glassfish sounds like it's a much better effort from Sun, but their history says they write great standards and lousy implementations.  I don't consider Glassfish to be a viable alternative.
    </prejudice-ahead>
```

WebSphere is a typical IBM project: twice the cost, half the functionality, poor documentation, and you have to buy all their nonsense (e.g., Eclipse based IDEs) to use it.

JBOSS isn't bad, but only because the price difference is so strongly in its favor.

I'd rather recommend Spring, Tomcat and ActiveMQ as an excellent alternative.  If EJBs are absolutely required, add OpenEJB to that mix.

2018 update: My affection for Java EE as a standard and its app server implementations has cooled in the last nine years.  I think a better answer is to go with Spring Boot.  Deploy an executable JAR on a JVM and never worry about a Java EE app server again.

Comment: Glassfish is excellent. Works very well, stable, fast, very easy to use out of the box, well documented. Specifically v2.1, v3 is still in development.

Comment: Sun's history still stands.  The fact that Glassfish is open source frees it from the questions surrounding WebLogic and Oracle's plans, but it remains to be seen what its adoption rate by companies will be.  I suspect that you'll see the usual pattern: it'll be embraced by small companies that can't afford licensing fees and scorned by Fortune 500 firms that are still leery of open source.

Answer (score 6):

> I'm saddened by Oracle's purchase. I
>   think that the talent has leaked away,
>   and Oracle has no clear idea of what
>   they want to do with WebLogic. They've
>   been stuck on version 10.1 for a few
>   years now.

There are a couple of problems with the above comment.  First, Oracle only purchased BEA 1.5 years ago, and even then that wasn't a DOJ approved transaction.  The final sale was not approved until something like 12 months ago.

Secondly, Oracle has made three releases of WebLogic since acquisition.  They are now on version 10.3.1 (or "11g").

Lastly, I think Oracle is - surprised to say that I am - moving in a clear direction.  With the recent acquisition of Sun, Oracle is now the primary provider of Java technology and has what many consider to be the leading Java application server.  They would not have invested in these companies and technologies without a clear plan to dominate the market.  I think Oracle's recent movements in the Java EE 6, WebLogic, and JDeveloper spaces show that they are pushing extremely hard to become the Java leader.

I'd still prefer JBoss; it's simple and just works.  I'm having loads of problems converting a Seam 2.x app from JBoss to Weblogic, but I'm hopeful that I will be successful at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would choose JBoss (community version) over Weblogic (Server) because it's free (you know, like in freedom). But that isn't answering the question, so...

I can see two main reasons for choosing Weblogic:

1. Weblogic is a well integrated product with a single configuration mechanism/file (easier* to configure and maintain).
2. Integration with Tuxedo.

*) The term easier is subjective. Most things are easy when you know how to do them.

Answer (score 3):

I had worked on jboss for a year and on weblogic for more than a year now, my experience with the web logic is good compared to jboss as weblogic is more stable and robust, it can handle more than 3000 concurrent requests without throwing a single exception where jboss failed to do so and admin console for the weblogic is excellent, but I think weblogic is more complex then jboss. As far as client is investing money on application server, my choice will be weblogic for sure.

Answer (score 3):

I've done 3 evaluations of WebLogic, JBoss, and WebSphere. WebLogic won every one of them, hands down. Having said that, my simplistic  guidance is this: use JBoss if you are NOT worried about scaling past several thousand concurrent users. However, if you intend to scale beyond that, you're going to need something with proven horsepower and robustness - that's WebLogic.

Note: app server vendors generally sacrifice technical features for stability. In other words, robustness is in dynamic tension with technical features. If you want new features, you get more bugs along with it. It surprises me how many technicians don't get that. But, if you think about why you don't rush out and buy the first new Windows OS version when it comes out, you'll understand perfectly why this is so.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

JBoss (Red Hat) has yet to release a commercially supported 100% Java EE 5-compliant container*.  There is a beta of JBoss 5 out.  Hopefully they won't be 3 years behind for Java EE 6.
JBoss is more concerned with their microcontainer than Java EE x because that's what they say their customers are more interested in.  I have never met any of those customers.  But it does mean that Java EE is a second-class citizen in their world.  As proof, their containers don't even ship in compliant mode; you have to tweak some config files to make it spec-compliant.

If Sun wasn't about to be consumed by the blackhole that is Oracle, I would recommend Glassfish.

- Red Hat does have a commercially supported 90% Java EE 5-compliant container.  JBoss 4.3 is their "stepping stone" to Java EE 5 version.

Comment: Robert, jBoss has a stable 5.x out, that is [Java EE 5 certified](http://java.sun.com/javaee/overview/compatibility.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

Well, i'd recommend using Spring+Tomcat and would introduce a full-blown JavaEE Application server only if i absolutely have to.
regarding Weblogic and JBoss, i'd prefer JBoss as Weblogic is more complex.

Comment: And don't fall for "We need an ESB because that's how it is done". Try a simple solution first.

Comment: I agree with "no ESB" and simple first.

Answer (score 1):

I developed Java based application for JBoss 4.x and 5.x for two years. After that i had to work with Weblogic 11. It wasn't easy to change my mind but now i  think, WL much better. More stable, faster and the Admin Console...like a dream..very easy to do settings and monitoring.

So, my choice is Weblogic.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you guys should consider TC Server, its a variant of Tomcat from Vmware. Might be good in an enterprise environment, since most of them should be able to work it out, as part of there virtualization deals.

http://www.vmware.com/products/vfabric-tcserver/

PS - I have used WLS extensively. For some applications it might be good. For some you really do not need it. So its very much driven by use case, scale etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the TCO Total Cost of Ownership

You must take into account these costs when using JBoss:

- Annual support subscriptions
- Higher on-going management and administration costs
- Impact of outages on cost
- Impact of product’s performance on cost
- Higher cost for interoperability testing and integration of the disparate OSS projects
- Complexity and cost of supporting an integrated OSS solution
- Insurance policy for indemnity protection
- Cost to support and maintain modified code
- Extra time and effort to deal with a myriad of open source licenses

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Do you happen to be in a company who likes to buy support from other companies like "Oracle" and don't really care about the money spending as long they are covered by the manufacturer ( Yes, I know Redhat sells the support also but some companies don't like to buy from them )

Anyway , this is a rather subjective question, I don't think there would be a correct answer.

Answer (score -5):

IBM released their BETA version of Java EE 6 server. So in case of Java EE 6 I think IBM would be the leader. Also JBoss is a good server but under heavy loads my experience shows it's not fully reliable compared to WebLogic and WebSphere.