# Weblogic Authenticate.authenticate equivalent in JBOSS 7

Tags: security, authentication, jboss, weblogic

What is the equivalent code in JBOSS 7 for Weblogic's login security module code `Authenticate.authenticate()`

Comment: You should tell us what you know about what Weblo' s`Authenticate.authenticate()` does, and you're trying to do with JBOSS

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you toroughfully read [JBOSS excellent migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+WebLogic+to+AS+7) .

> WebLogic provides a proprietary ServletAuthentication class to perform programmatic login. In **JBoss AS 7**, you can use the ***standard Java EE6 Servlet 3.0 `HttpServletRequest.login()`*** method to perform programmatic login or you can define a  element in the `web.xml` file.
>
> To enable programmatic login, you must ***replace the WebLogic proprietary code*** with one of the following:
>
> - You can add the following annotations to the Servlet class that performs the authentication.
>
>   ```
>   // Imports for annotations
>   import javax.annotation.security.DeclareRoles;
>   import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
>   import javax.servlet.annotation.HttpConstraint;
>   import javax.servlet.annotation.ServletSecurity;
>
>   @WebServlet("/securedUrlPattern")
>   @ServletSecurity(@HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed = { "myRole" }))
>   @DeclareRoles("myRole")
>   public class SecuredServlet extends HttpServlet {
>     //Rest of code
>   }
>   ```

---

> - If you prefer not to use the standard servlet, you can instead add a  element containing a dummy URL pattern to the `web.xml` file. This notifies JBoss to create a default Authenticator. Failure to create a  element in the `web.xml` file may result in the error message "No authenticator available for programmatic login".

Another reason we should [choose JBOSS over Weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305980/weblogic-or-jboss)